# Colllection_check_boxes syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using helper collection_check_boxes:

```
<li class="form-fields__group">

    <label>Ownership type</label>
      <div class="field">
        <%= collection_check_boxes (:freelancer, :ownership_type_ids, OwnershipType.all, :id, :title) %>


      </div>
    </li>
```

In console error:

```
SyntaxError (/home/ubuntu/workspace/app/views/freelancers/edit.html.erb:192: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
...ction_check_boxes (:freelancer, :ownership_type_ids, Ownersh...
...                               ^
/home/ubuntu/workspace/app/views/freelancers/edit.html.erb:192: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting &. or :: or '[' or '.'
...pe_ids, OwnershipType.all, :id, :title) );@output_buffer.saf...
...                               ^
/home/ubuntu/workspace/app/views/freelancers/edit.html.erb:192: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
...nershipType.all, :id, :title) );@output_buffer.safe_append='
...                               ^):
```

Why this error? What wrong with collection_check_boxes?

Comment: Remove space. <%= collection_check_boxes(:freelancer, :ownership_type_ids, OwnershipType.all, :id, :title) %>

Comment: I will post my answer below and please accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
<%= collection_check_boxes (:freelancer, :ownership_type_ids, OwnershipType.all, :id, :title) %>
```

Remove space:

```
<%= collection_check_boxes(:freelancer, :ownership_type_ids, OwnershipType.all, :id, :title) %>
```